# Regular & Spring abstracted Ignite transactions fail with IllegalStateException post manual reconnect with clientReconnectDisabled as true

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite, gridgain

We are running version 2.4 & using Spring [IgniteSpringBean](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.4.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteSpringBean.html), [SpringTransactionManager](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.4.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/transactions/spring/SpringTransactionManager.html) & [Spring Data](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/v2.4/docs/spring-data) repositories for cluster & transactional cache access.

Since we have been having a lot of IgniteClientDisconnectedException related issues, i am writing a manual segmentation resolver (by disabling automatic client reconnection with clientReconnectDisabled set to true) which would detect this condition (using a simple cache query that runs periodically) & initiate a disconnect via [IgniteSpringBean#close](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.4.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteSpringBean.html#close--) followed by a reconnect as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435912/regular-spring-data-based-cache-operations-fail-with-cachestoppedexception-pos/51493713)

I had other issues with cache access which i resolved as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435912/regular-spring-data-based-cache-operations-fail-with-cachestoppedexception-pos/51493713#51493713)

But the problem is that any time i try to use a spring transaction annotated method it fails creating a transaction with an IllegalStateException mentioning that the grid is in invalid state.

I suspect its again the same issue that i faced earlier (referenced above) with stale references and might need to handle it in the code by updating the kernel reference in SpringTransactionManager. I am trying out that fix & will update if it works.

In the meanwhile if someone has a easier/quicker fix approach/suggestion, please share the same.

Below is the exception,

```
com.***.dcm.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Error while creating the definition. Message is : Could not create Ignite transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [igniteInstanceName=null, state=STOPPED]
    at com.***.dcm.topology.middleware.controller.TopologyServiceControllerHelper.createTopologyDefinition(TopologyServiceControllerHelper.java:124)
    at com.***.dcm.topology.middleware.controller.TopologyServiceController.createTopologyDefinition(TopologyServiceController.java:129)
2018-07-24 14:11:00.519 ERROR b731ba99e9b2 --- [nio-7099-exec-1] .d.t.m.c.TopologyServiceControllerHelper : Error while creating the definition. Message is : Could not create Ignite transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [igniteInstanceName=null, state=STOPPED]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: IgniteClientDisconnectedException has the reconnectFuture() method that returns the future that will be completed when the reconnection happens.
Thus you could block the client and wait until the future will be resolved and the client became active.
For example:
public void checkAndReconnect(){
 try{
  // make ignite query
 }catch(IgniteClientDisconnectedException ex){
    ex.reconnectFuture().get();
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix that i mentioned earlier worked. For others that may be facing this issue, the fix involves updating the ignite kernel reference in SpringTransactionManager post the reconnect.

Below are the needed code changes,

In SpringTransactionManager.java,

```
/**
 * @author mlekshma
 * 
 * @param ignite
 */
protected void setResourceFactory(final Ignite ignite) {
    this.ignite = ignite;
}
```

I am using an anonymous inner class of SpringTransactionManager to hack the injection because of ignite-spring integration issues in 2.4 (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521421/ignitespringbean-ignite-springtransactionmanager-do-not-work-together-anymore)),

```
/**
 * @author mlekshma
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("com.***.***")
@EnableIgniteRepositories(basePackages={"com.***.***"})
@ImportResource("classpath:ignite-client-conf.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:ignite-client.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class IgniteClientConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IgniteClientConfig.class);

    public IgniteClientConfig() {
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("igniteInstance")
    @Primary
    @Lazy
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final SpringTransactionManager springTransactionManager = new SpringTransactionManager() {

            private boolean isInitialized = false;

            @Override 
            public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
                if (isInitialized) {
                    if(((IgniteKernal) getResourceFactory()).context().gateway().getState() == GridKernalState.STOPPED) {
                        IgniteKernal igniteKernal = (IgniteKernal) Ignition.ignite(getIgniteInstanceName());
                        if(igniteKernal != null) {
                            setResourceFactory(igniteKernal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * @param event
             */
            @EventListener
            public void handleContextRefresh(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) throws Exception {
                LOGGER.info("Setting up tx support..");
                super.afterPropertiesSet();
                isInitialized = true;
            }
        };
        // Use default grid client instance created..
        springTransactionManager.setTransactionConcurrency(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC);
        return springTransactionManager;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Closing cache after re-connection is fixed in the 2.5 version(
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2766).

As I understand you want to create a new ignite instance and use one for SpringTransactionManager.
I suppose that it is not proper way because there are cache instances for example in IgniteRepositoryImpl#cache that required to be reinitialized too.

I do recommend to use IgniteClientDisconnectedException#reconnectFuture()
method that returns the future that will be completed when the reconnection happens.
Thus you could block the client and wait until the future will be resolved and the client became active.
For example:

```
public void checkAndReconnect(){
    try{
        // make ignite query
    }catch(IgniteClientDisconnectedException ex){
       ex.reconnectFuture().get();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps to resolve connection issue.